# Javascript regex to match last word regardless of specials characters

Tags: javascript, regex

We use this script to alter the last word in a sentence.

```
$div = $('.cPageHeader h2');
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\w+?)$/, '<span class="cOrange">$1</span>'));
```

This works well as long as there are no special chars involved.

As soon as we have a header like `<h2>International fancy stüff</h2>` the highlighting goes wrong. Only ff will be highlighted. The same error occurs if we have one of the chars at the end of the line `(!-.?)`.

Can someone alter the script, so that the last whole word (including attached punctuation) and regardless of any accented chars, will be highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$div = $('.cPageHeader h2');
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\S+?)$/, '<span class="cOrange">$1</span>'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sb7Nk/).

This basically looks for all the non white-space characters at the end of your string, although if your string *ends* with white-space, there'll be no highlight (so it might be worth trimming the string *first*, just to be sure.

The following replicates the above, but is a little more tolerant of trailing white-space:

```
var $div = $('#demo');
$div.html($div.text().replace(/\b(\S+?)(\b|(?:\s+))$/, '<span class="cOrange">$1</span>'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sb7Nk/2/).

This matches:

- `\b`: a word-boundary;
- `\S+`: a sequence of one, or more, non white-space characters;
- `(\b|(?:\s+))`: another word-boundary *or* a sequence of one, or more, white-space characters.

Updated once more, because the numbered-matches (the `$1`) from your original expression are apparently deprecated, or will soon be (though I *cannot* find a reference to back up that particular recollection, so perhaps take it with a pinch of salt), and to use a function instead:

```
var $div = $('#demo');
$div.html($div.text().replace(/\b(\S+?)(\b|(?:\s+))$/, function(a){
    return '<span class="cOrange">' + a + '</span>';
}));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sb7Nk/3/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).

Comment: Nifty. `\S` means "anything but spacing chars", including `\t` and `\n`

Comment: I know the use of numbered group references like `$1` is discouraged in Perl, but I've never heard that about JavaScript.  Also, it's not correct to use `\b` here.  That will only work if the first and last characters are always word characters, and you can't assume they will be.  That's why you had to switch from `\w+` to `\S+` in the first place.

Comment: Oh, is it just Perl? I honestly can't remember where I came across the warning (and Google's not turning anything meaningful up in my searches).

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need:

```
$div.text().replace(/(\S+)$/, '<span class="cOrange">$1</span>')
```

You want to include the trailing punctuation in the match anyway, so `\w+` never was the right tool for the job.  And this way you don't have to deal with making it treat non-ASCII characters like `ü` as word characters.

Just FYI, there's no point using a reluctant quantifier like `\S+?`, since you're matching all the way to the end of the string.  It's not incorrect in this case, just pointless.

Comment: I think you'd need to use `html()`, though, unless he wants the `<span>...</span>` in the actual text?

Comment: I removed that part so I could concentrate on the regex-related stuff.